# Widget null pointer exception on orientation change

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-widget, android-orientation

I have a nasty problem with a NumberPicker and an ImageView working totally fine in portrait and producing null pointer exceptions on orientation change (it took me a while to figure out that it only worked in portrait mode, as i first thought the orientation change in it self was the issue).

So here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_viewer);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        mTouchImageView = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoView);
        mTimePicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        mTimePickerScreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.timePickerScreen);

        mImageButtonCrop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCrop);

        mTimePickerScreen.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        mTimePicker.setVisibility(NumberPicker.INVISIBLE);
        mTimePicker.setMaxValue(15);
        mTimePicker.setMinValue(1);
        ...
```

The line `mTimePickerScreen.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);` causes the error, and if id comment it out the next one would and so on. After allot of lines commented out i concluded that the problem was only with the `nTimePicker` and `nTimePickerScreen`.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/TimePickerTheme">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/timePickerScreen"
            android:background="@color/black_translucent"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to also add the above XML lines to a landscape layout XML in res/layout-land and now everything works fine. I know this is probably an amateur mistake, but i searched a lot for a solution and couldn't find one so i thought this might help someone.